# Loop through subfolder and copy file with specific extension

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, shutil, arcpy

I have a parent folder, lets call it "workspace". Within this parent folder, there are sub folders which have further subfolders that have a specific naming convention. It looks something like this:

```
    - Workspace 
      - Subfolder A 
         - Name 
         - Image 
         - Class 
      - Subfolder B 
         - Name 
         - Image 
         - Class 
      - Subfolder C 
         - Name  
         - Image 
         - Class
```

I need help of some sort or direction writing a script that iterates through A-C within the workspace and copying all files in the "images" folder of each subfolder to a new destination.

This is what I have so far:

```
import os
import arcpy
import shutil
import fnmatch

workspace = "source"
pfolder = "rootdir"

files = os.listdir(workspace)
print (files)

test = workspace + "\\scratch.gdb"
if os.path.exists(test):
    print ("Scratch GDB already exists")
    shutil.rmtree(test)
    scratch = arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(workspace,"scratch")
    print ("Original Scratch GDB removed and new GDB created ")
else:
    scratch = arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(workspace,"scratch")
    print ("Scratch GDB has been created")

def main():
        for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(pfolder):
            for file in filenames:
                if fnmatch.fnmatch(file,"*.jpg")==True:
                    shutil.copy2(file,scratch)
                    print("Files have been copied!")
                else:
                    print("Error in copying files")
```

I want to copy all jpg files in that subdirectory and place them in a geodatabase. For some reason it does not run the line of code that executes the loop and copy.

Comment: Where do you call your `main` function?

Answer (score 0):

Shutil may not work, to input a raster file in a geodatabase you [cannot use the file extension in the name](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/copy-raster.htm).

The code below is your code with minimal modification (like using CopyRaster_management instead copy2) to work, so it may not be the best code because I was not worried about that, but works:

```
import os
import arcpy
import shutil
import fnmatch

workspace = "C:\\Teste\\"
pfolder = r'C:\Teste\\'

files = os.listdir(workspace)
print (files)

tests = workspace + "\\scratch.gdb"
sGdbP = "C:\\Teste\\scratch.gdb\\"
if os.path.exists(tests):
    print ("Scratch GDB already exists")
    shutil.rmtree(tests)
    scratch = arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(workspace,"scratch")
    print ("Original Scratch GDB removed and new GDB created ")
else:
    scratch = arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(workspace,"scratch")
    print ("Scratch GDB has been created")

for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(pfolder):
    for file in filenames:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(file,"*.tif")==True:
            try:
                arcpy.env.workspace = dirname
                in_data = file
                out_data = sGdbP + file[:-4] # cannot use extension
                arcpy.CopyRaster_management(in_data, out_data)
            except:
                print "Raster To Geodatabase example failed."
                print arcpy.GetMessages()
            print("Files have been copied!")

print "End of script"
```